# Change Sharepoint online Background

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I would like to know how change backgroung sharepoint to custom background with username of user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you provide the screenshots for further research.

If you want to custom background of the user's username in list view, we can use the css below to achieve it in classic UI. We can add the style into master page using SharePoint designer.

```
<style>
.ms-vb-user{
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
```

For modern UI, we need inject a custom Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) using SPFx application customizer to achieve it. The solution below for your reference.

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss)